# Cancel ffmpeg from javascript frontend

Tags: javascript, php, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg with php to convert video uploaded by the user, the frontend written in javascript/html sends the file to a php script in the backend that does the conversion with exec.

How can I cancel the conversion when the user click cancel from the frontend? please note that the file is uploaded and the conversion is started already.

Comment: "Killing process with PHP" has been asked here many times.

Comment: I am not sure how it is in php because I never done it usign php, but You would need to kill its id something like kill -9 {$pid} try getting the pid id using the fallowing in your execution "> dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!". Again, this is just me thinking since I do this on linux almost 24/7 in bash scripting.